# Alter URL- To Hide String in URL

Tags: mysql

I am having below URL I want to hide 'target' and 'pageid' in mysql to avoid SQL injection.
https://www.stmtps.com/rigid/index.php?*target=pages&page_id=MonthlySpecials*

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the expected output? And what do you mean by Hide. Please add some more details to your question.

Comment: If you want to hide target and pageid, then use `POST` method instead of `GET`.

Comment: Please add more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?p=profile&id=$1
```

Should work for :

```
www.domain.com/index.php?p=profile&id=20
```

to

```
www.domain.com/profile/20/profile-friendly-name
```